# Quaternion deltas with Arbitrary Coordinate System

Tags: 3d, coordinates, orientation, quaternions

I'm trying to wrap my head around some Quaternion math and would really appreciate your help!

- I have a sensor fusion chip which produces orientation Quaternions with respect to the coordinate system of the chip. I will call this reference axis frame **F**. It is composed of the axes **X, Y,** and **Z**.
- I want to be able to establish an arbitrary up axis and store its value as a Quaternion with respect to **F**. I will call this orientation  quaternion **Qp**.
- By using **Qp**, I want to rotate the frame **F** to produce frame **F'**, which is composed of the axes **X', Y',** and **Z'**
- In this example, I have chosen **Qp** such that the **Z' = X, X' = Z, Y' =Y**

---

I now want to :

- Sample the Sensor's position Quaternion
- Convert this position into euler angles
- Keep track of total travel along the three euler axes.
- In the example above, if I rotate about the axis **Z'**, I should see the Z euler angles increasing/decreasing accordingly.

However, no matter what I have tried up until now, I cannot obtain this result. If I rotate about the **Z'** axis, the X euler values are changing (This corresponds with the above where **Z' = X**)

My question is:

- What combination of math must I do to obtain this result? It seems like simply subtracting **Qp** from my measured positions should work, but the resulting Quaternions are always still with respect to my original reference frame **F**.
- I also want this to work for any arbitrarily chosen **Qp** - the axes **X', Y', Z'** may not always be simple replacements as they are above.

If this is not enough information, I will provide more. Thanks for your time everyone!

Answer (score 1):

I have a couple of problems with the question. First, a quaternion specifies the entire attitude, while just identifying an "up" vector as you propose doesn't do that.  You need two vectors, as one way, to define a new frame. Beinning from "up" you need one more.

Anyway if it returns quaternions they are OF the chip frame WITH RESPECT TO some other frame: which one?  This language seems stilted but will pay off in clarity later when doing the math, so write QF2p == Quaternion expressing orientation of part "p" w.r.t. the chip Frame or something.  The quaternion transforms vectors from chip (F)rame to (p)art frame.  (Sorry so pedantic) (Also, trying to use your subscripts, renaming "Qp").

Moving on: "sample the sensor's quaternion"  Your sensor yields a quaternion?  I thought you had a chip that computed quaternions given orientation.  If you have something that determines orienation, what is it's output?  Possibly a different Quat? (sorry, confused).

convert Quat --> euler is trivial see wikipedia, but watch out for polarity and quaternioni definition, there are at least 2.  Is this where you need assistance?

"Total travel along the 3 euler axes" is good but unconventional language: euler angles are generally not "axes" 'cause not orthogonal, but you can integrate 'em...

Rewriting the experiment: if you rotate about z' you should see the psi euler angle change.  Euler is not a vector or axis system, but I will generally order them [psi, theta, phi] about z,y,x, respectively. Note in small angles you'd prefer [dPhi, dTheta, dPsi] so the small angle orientation change (part of the quaternion) is aligned with the angular rates that made it happen. Also (horrors) there are innumerable euler angle sequences you could choose & there're some assumptions of "standard aircraft" in choosing the ones I list here.  Perhaps the point is, if you did your experiment, without seeing your chip's design sheet, I would've guessed the dPsi would move and that it'd be the first Euler angle.  It is the first in sequence.  How do you go about associating it with "X"?  ...maybe that's the mistake.

"What math must I do?"  Attitude subtraction is quaternion multiplication.  You can't literally subtract quaternions.

best regards.